# linux shell script exits once reached to a certain point in code

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, sh, raspbian

When my code reaches a certain point it closes and doesn’t finish.  Why is it doing this? By the way, it does create the user and assign it to the group; once you enter `y` after it prompts you that the group doesn’t exist and would you like to create it, then the terminal closes and doesn’t continue with the rest of the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
let repeat=1
let counter=0
while [ $repeat -eq 1 ];
        do
        echo "Please enter the username for the created user"
        read username
        sudo useradd -m $username
        echo ""
        sudo passwd $username
        let counter=$counter+1
        while [ $repeat -eq 1 ];
                do
                echo "please enter the name of the group to put the user into"
                read group
                if [ $(getent group $group) ]; then #line 17 
                        sudo usermod -G $group,sudo $username
                        let repeat=0
                else
                        echo "The group "$group$" does not exist on our system"
                        echo "Do you want to create it as a new group (y)"
                        read input
                        if [ [ $input == "y" ] ]; then
                                sudo groupadd $groups
                                sudo usermod -G $group,sudo $username
                                let repeat=0

                        fi

                fi

         done
         echo $username" has beem added to the group "$group
   done
   echo "You have now created "$counter" new user(s) and have added them to   their new group(s)"
```

Comment: `if [ [ $input == "y" ] ]; then` is a syntax error. You have too many `[` pairs.

Comment: Even when I changed it to if [ $input = "y" ]; then    it still did the same error

Comment: You want to quote `"$input"` there (and more-or-less all variables when you use them). How are you running the script? Add `set -x` to the top and see what happens just before it exits.

Comment: Does the same exact thing and I could not see what happend as it closed too quick

Comment: How are you running this? What happens if you run it *from* a local terminal window instead of via whatever mechanism you are using that spawns a new terminal window?

Comment: I'm clicking on the file on the GUI and it pops up and option to run it in the terminal which I am doing , I will try to open it in the terminal via ./{filename} later

Comment: A good first step in debugging shell scripts is to use the `-x` option to the shell.  Post the (end of) the trace output (or investigate it yourself to understand what's happening(.